# How to populate values inside a new column based values from other columns in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I  have dataframe `df` has shown below.

```
  df
DATA ELEMENT    PORT    LOCATION    P_RISK  S_RISK  W_RISK  Total_Risk
Event 1000     SGSIN                      0       0       0       0
Event 2000     MYKUL                      0       1       0       1
Event 3000                PARIS           0       0       1       1
Event 4000                LYON            1       0       0       1
Event 1000     USNYK                      0       0       0       0
Event 2000     INCOK                      0       0       1       1
Event 3000                MUMBAI          0       0       0       0
Event 4000                LAHORE          1       0       0       1
Event 2000     INCOK                      0       0       0       0
Event 3000                PARIS           0       0       0       0
```

Condition

*If `Data Element` is 1000 or 2000 and `Total Risk` is 1 then populate the new column `comment` with the With `Risk Name + PORT

*If `Data Element` is 3000 or 4000 and `Total Risk` is 1 then populate the new column `comment` with the With `Risk Name + LOCATION`

*If `Total Risk` is 0 then populate No Risk Indentified

Expected Output

```
df
    DATA ELEMENT    PORT    LOCATION    P_RISK  S_RISK  W_RISK  Total_Risk  Comment
    Event 1000     SGSIN                      0       0       0       0     No Risk Indentified
    Event 2000     MYKUL                      0       1       0       1     S_RISK  predicted at  MYKUL
    Event 3000                PARIS           0       0       1       1     W_RISK predicted at  PARIS
    Event 4000                LYON            1       0       0       1     P_RISK  predicted at  LYON
    Event 1000     USNYK                      0       0       0       0     No Risk Indentified
    Event 2000     INCOK                      0       0       1       1     W_RISK predicted at  INCOK
    Event 3000                MUMBAI          0       0       0       0     No Risk Indentified
    Event 4000                LAHORE          1       0       0       1     P_RISK  predicted at  LAHORE
    Event 2000     INCOK                      0       0       0       0     No Risk Indentified
    Event 3000                PARIS           0       0       0       0     No Risk Indentified
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am use `dot` with `np.where`

```
s2=df.filter(like='_RISK')
s2=s2.dot(s2.columns)
df['new']=np.where(s2=='' ,'No Risk Indentified',s2 + ' predict at ' +df.PORT.mask(df.PORT=='',df.LOCATION))
df
Out[35]: 
    DATA  ELEMENT   PORT  ... W_RISK  Total_Risk                     new
0  Event     1000  SGSIN  ...      0           0     No Risk Indentified
1  Event     2000  MYKUL  ...      0           1   S_RISKpredict atMYKUL
2  Event     3000         ...      1           1   W_RISKpredict atPARIS
3  Event     4000         ...      0           1    P_RISKpredict atLYON
4  Event     1000  USNYK  ...      0           0     No Risk Indentified
5  Event     2000  INCOK  ...      1           1   W_RISKpredict atINCOK
6  Event     3000         ...      0           0     No Risk Indentified
7  Event     4000         ...      0           1  P_RISKpredict atLAHORE
8  Event     2000  INCOK  ...      0           0     No Risk Indentified
9  Event     3000         ...      0           0     No Risk Indentified
[10 rows x 9 columns]
```

Method 2

```
s2=df.filter(like='_RISK').ne(0).stack()                                                                             
s2=s2[s2].reset_index(level=1)                                                                                       
df['new']=(s2['level_1'] + ' predict at ' +df.PORT.mask(df.PORT=='',df.LOCATION)).fillna('No Risk Indentified')
```

Comment: @ Getting an Error `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: @Rahulrajan try `s2=df.filter(like='_RISK').ne(0)`

Comment: @WeNYoBen, I have around 2000 records and its taking lot time to execute. Its still running. Is there an alternate way

Comment: @Rahulrajan I am not sure ,why , in your data you have dummy variable , dot is convert dummy variable back

Comment: @WeNYoBen, Its still running .Is there any other way using like using normal if -else to achieve the result

Comment: @WeNYoBen, The methord 2 excutes first two lines in seconds comapred earlier method. But now fails in third line due `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @Rahulrajan change to `s2=s2[s2].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).head(1)
`? you have some line contain multiple 1

Comment: @WeNYoBen,Works perfectly

Comment: @WeNYoBen, Just a small doubt, what if I have values for Port and Location  for status 3000 and 4000

Comment: @Rahulrajan you mean you have numeric value in Port ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen, For a record I will have both Port Name and Location Name mentioned rather than either them being null.

Comment: @Rahulrajan just do `(s2['level_1'] + ' predict at ' +df.PORT+df.LOCATION).fillna('No Risk Indentified')` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202768/discussion-between-rahul-rajan-and-wenyoben).